# Enums in Structures

Tags: c, struct, enums, structure, unions

My C file has a structure and an enum in it.

```
struct list{
    enum {1 , 2 ,3, 4};
    //defining a variable 'a'
};
```

I want the data type of variable to depend on the selection of enum. Eg: if enum '1' was selected 'a' should be 'int', '2' for float etc.

Comment: The data can be stored in a `union`. A separate variable is needed to indicate which member of the `union` is being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to fix the `enum`; you can't define a list of numbers like that.
Then you'll probably use a `union`.

```
struct list
{
    enum { T_UNKNOWN, T_INT, T_FLOAT } type;
    union
    {
        int     v_int;
        float   v_float;
    };   // C11 anonymous union
};
```

Now you can define:

```
struct list l1 = { .type = T_INT, .v_int = -937 };
struct list l2 = { .type = T_FLOAT, .v_float = 1.234 };

if (l1.type == l2.type)
    …the values can be compared…
else
    …the values can't be compared directly…

printf("l1.type = %d; l1.v_int = %d\n", l1.type, l1.v_int);
```

If you don't have C11 and anonymous unions available, you'll need to give the union a name:

```
struct list
{
    enum { T_UNKNOWN, T_INT, T_FLOAT } type;
    union
    {
        int     v_int;
        float   v_float;
    } u;   // C99 or C90
};
```

Assuming C99 (so you have designated initializers), you can use:

```
struct list l1 = { .type = T_INT, .u = { .v_int = 1 } };
```

and

```
printf("l1.type = %d; l1.u.v_int = %d\n", l1.type, l1.u.v_int);
```

If you don't have C99, then you can only initialize the first element of the union, the `v_int` member.

It is traditional to use a very short (single letter) name for the union; it isn't interesting in the code, but it was necessary until C11.

Comment: That is a lovely walk through the support at various language revisions.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. But whats the use of T_UNKNOWN ? can the two variables be named the same( rather than v_int and v_float);                                `struct list l1 = { .type = T_INT, .v = -937 };
struct list l2 = { .type = T_FLOAT, .v= 1.234 };` I want this to happen

Comment: The value `T_UNKNOWN` simply occupies the value 0 so `T_INT` is 1 and `T_FLOAT` is 2, as requested.  It could also serve as a default initializer indicating that the type has not been set.  No, you can’t use the same name for both `v_int` and `v_float`; the names must be different for the different types.